# Oracle SQL inserting multiple rows and splitting data from single foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Trying to make an insert that gets its data from a table and splits it into two (or more) rows in another table while retaining the foreign key from the parent table.

For this example lets say parent table is `Fruit` and has columns:

```
fruit_id, num_fruit
```

The table I am inserting to is `Fruit_Sub` with columns:

```
Fruit_Sub_id, Fruit_id_FK, fruit_name, num_sub_fruit
```

Each row of fruit that is to be inserted into `Fruit_sub` knowing that from `Fruit.num_fruit` there is always 3 apples and the rest are bananas.

If `Fruit` looks like this:

```
fruit_id    num_fruit
----------------------
   1            5
   2            9
   3            4
```

I want to insert data into `Fruit_sub` like this:

```
fruit_sub_id    fruit_id_fk   fruit_name    num_sub_fruit
-----------------------------------------------------
   1                1           apples      3
   2                1           bananas     2
   3                2           apples      3
   4                2           bananas     6
   5                3           apples      3
   6                3           bananas     1
```

So far all of my cracks at it aren't even recognizable as SQL. This one's just a bit beyond me.

Comment: Can you provide your queries, which you already tried?

Comment: Do you ever had occasions where num_fruit is 3 or less than 3? Ie, no bananas?

Answer (score 0):

You could union two queries and then wrap with a row_number window function to generate the sub_id.

```
select 
  row_number() over (order by fruit_id, fruit_name) as fruit_sub_id, 
  fruit_id, 
  fruit_name, 
  num_sub_fruit
from (
 select 
  fruit_id, 
  'apples' as fruit_name, 
  3 as num_sub_fruit
 from fruit
 union
 select 
  fruit_id, 
  'bananas', 
  num_fruit - 3 
 from fruit
 )z
order by 1,2,3
```

| FRUIT_SUB_ID | FRUIT_ID | FRUIT_NAME | NUM_SUB_FRUIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | apples | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | bananas | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | apples | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | bananas | 6 |
| 5 | 3 | apples | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | bananas | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LC9Bv_RQ)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use Case expression with UNPIVOT

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        (   Select 1 "FRUIT_ID", 5 "NUM_FRUIT" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "FRUIT_ID", 9 "NUM_FRUIT" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "FRUIT_ID", 4 "NUM_FRUIT" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  ROWNUM "FRUIT_SUB_ID", FRUIT_ID_FK, FRUIT_NAME, 
        Case When FRUIT_NAME = 'apples' Then NUM_APPLES Else NUM_BANANAS End "NUM_SUB_FRUIT"
From    (   Select  FRUIT_ID "FRUIT_ID_FK", 'apples' "APPLES", 3 "NUM_APPLES", 'bananas' "BANANAS", NUM_FRUIT - 3 "NUM_BANANAS"
            From    tbl
        ) UNPIVOT ( FRUIT_NAME
                    FOR FRUIT IN(APPLES as 'apples', BANANAS as 'bananas')  )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
FRUIT_SUB_ID FRUIT_ID_FK FRUIT_NAME NUM_SUB_FRUIT
------------ ----------- ---------- -------------
           1           1 apples                 3
           2           1 bananas                2
           3           2 apples                 3
           4           2 bananas                6
           5           3 apples                 3
           6           3 bananas                1  */
```

If there is a possibility that there is a row(s) with NUM_FRUIT less than 3 - you could handle it with Case expression too:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        (   Select 1 "FRUIT_ID", 5 "NUM_FRUIT" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "FRUIT_ID", 2 "NUM_FRUIT" From Dual 
        )   
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  ROWNUM "FRUIT_SUB_ID", FRUIT_ID_FK, FRUIT_NAME, 
        Case When FRUIT_NAME = 'apples' Then NUM_APPLES Else NUM_BANANAS End "NUM_SUB_FRUIT"
From    (   Select  FRUIT_ID "FRUIT_ID_FK", 
                    'apples' "APPLES", 
                    Case When NUM_FRUIT >= 3 Then 3 Else NUM_FRUIT End "NUM_APPLES", 
                    'bananas' "BANANAS", 
                    Case When NUM_FRUIT >= 3 Then NUM_FRUIT - 3 Else 0 End "NUM_BANANAS"
            From    tbl
      ) UNPIVOT ( FRUIT_NAME
                  FOR FRUIT IN(APPLES as 'apples', BANANAS as 'bananas')  )
/*    R e s u l t :
FRUIT_SUB_ID FRUIT_ID_FK FRUIT_NAME NUM_SUB_FRUIT
------------ ----------- --------- -------------
           1           1 apples                3
           2           1 bananas               2
           3           2 apples                2
           4           2 bananas               0  */
```